# What makes xset -dpms on my machine?

Tags: xserver

I always xset +dpms.
But nearly every day dpms is switched off again.
How can I find out what program is doing this?

Comment: Most likely, the dpms setting is not recognised on restart due to a minhor incompatibility. Fallback to default is applied then. You can however easily work around by adding `/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && xset +dpms"` to startup applications (Add to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add). If it solves your issue, I'll write it as an answer, please mention.

Comment: Ok I watch if it is only reset after hybernation or if it is reset during the machine running.

Comment: It looks like the program "viber" is doing this when I make video chats.

Answer (score 1):

The messenger "viber" switches dpms off during video chats.

Comment: Good catch! It might be worth to report this as a bug. (Desktop) applications shouldn't interfere with screen power states. That's a job for the display manager which can be instrumented via DBus on all Linux desktops.

Comment: Of course Viber is closed source and doesn't have a (public) issue tracker. The best I could find is their [support ticket form](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/emails/new).

Comment: I did use this ticket form but they do not understand what I want. This is only for customers which cannot open their microphone and similar things.

Comment: I suspected as much.